# permalink construction for a custom post type using standard wordpress categories

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

I didn't find any similar issue: in fact the problem of taxonomy are usually related to a standard "custom post + custom category" model.
What I want is to obtain a specific taxonomy url with main WP category "shared between" custom post.
The reason is that I want my user to manage all the categories together.
This is my code:

```
if(!function_exists('testimonial_post')):
function testimonial_post(){
    $labels = array( 
        'name'                  => esc_html__( 'Testimonial', 'Testimonial' ),
        'singular_name'         => esc_html__( 'Testimonial', 'Testimonial' ),
        'menu_name'             => esc_html__( 'Testimonial' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => esc_html__( 'Parent Testimonial'  ),
        'all_items'             => esc_html__( 'All Testimonial'  ),
        'view_item'             => esc_html__( 'View Testimonial'  ),
        'add_new_item'          => esc_html__( 'Add New Testimonial'  ),
        'add_new'               => esc_html__( 'New Testimonial'  ),
        'edit_item'             => esc_html__( 'Edit Testimonial'  ),
        'update_item'           => esc_html__( 'Update Testimonial'  ),
        'search_items'          => esc_html__( 'Search Testimonial' ),
        'not_found'             => esc_html__( 'No article found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => esc_html__( 'No article found in Trash' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-quote',
        'supports'              => array( 'title','editor','thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category' )
    );
    register_post_type('testimonial',$args);
}
add_action('init','testimonial_post');
endif;
```

And it works fine. I also have a custom post template.
The deatail page of a single testimonial entity is correctly loaded at this perma:

```
mysite.it/testimonial/john-rossi/
```

But permas for categories and archive don't work.

Call to the category:

```
mysite.it/category/allievi/
```

no results
(where "allievi" is the main category assigned to testimonials, so... no post in this category, but lots of testimonial custom type).

Call to the custom post archive:

```
mysite.it/testimonial/
```

(not found)

I'd like to obtain a specific url for categories and custom post keeping my custom post on the main WP category taxonomy.
Something like

```
mysite.it/testimonial/
```

for a complete list.

```
mysite.it/testimonial/allievi/2018-2019
```

for a specific category>subcategory list.

Is that possibile?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite? I think you can have the customization you want with the help of that hooks or methods.